# How do I create a loop that will actively switch variables?

Tags: javascript, loops

```
function calc() {
  var a = document.getElementById("yValue").value;
  var b = document.getElementById("yValue2").value;
  var c = document.getElementById("yValue3").value;
  var d = document.getElementById("yValue4").value;
  for (i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    var x = document.getElementById("amt").value;
    var e = Number(a) + Number(b);
    var f = Number(b) + Number(c);
    var g = Number(c) + Number(d);
    var h = Number(d);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = e + ", " + f + ", " + g + ", " + h;
    var a = e;
    var b = f;
    var c = g;
    var d = h;
  }
}
```

I am trying to set this up so that the variables e f g h can be moved to a b c d so that the math that is applied can just continue to loop but it is not working, can anyone help me?

Comment: For starters, why are you getting the value of `x` *inside* of the loop? Don't you need `x` to enter the loop in the first place? Also, don't put `var` in front of a variable unless you're making a new one. In this case it won't affect you but it's something that's good to understand. Finally, you're repeatedly overwriting your output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't initialzied x.

```
  for (i = 0; i < x; i++) { //x is not defined
    var x = document.getElementById("amt").value;
```

Should probably be:

```
var x = document.getElementById("amt").value;
  for (i = 0; i < x; i++) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code might give you expected results.

```
function calc() {
  var a = document.getElementById("yValue").value;
  var b = document.getElementById("yValue2").value;
  var c = document.getElementById("yValue3").value;
  var d = document.getElementById("yValue4").value;

  var x = document.getElementById("amt").value;

  for (i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    var e = Number(a) + Number(b);
    var f = Number(b) + Number(c);
    var g = Number(c) + Number(d);
    var h = Number(d);

    a = e;
    b = f;
    c = g;
    d = h;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML + "<br/>" + e + ", " + f + ", " + g + ", " + h;
  }
}
```

Comment: My problem now is what Mike C said, I keep just overwriting my output, when really I want to print every iteration of the loop. Any ideas?

Comment: Changed code to fit in your requirement. Now the new values will be appended to old contents hence you will get multiple rows corresponding to each iteration. Let me know if this is what you expect and the solution is working.

Comment: Yes that is working! thank you so much, I was having so much trouble with the line break for some reason